# ¿Cómo mostrar la vista controles de selección, copy, paste... solapando la ActionBar en Android?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Tengo un `EditText` multilinea cuando selecciono una palabra con doble toque, se muestra la vista establecida por el sistema, donde el usuario puede selecciona, copiar, cortar, pegar etc...

El problema es que me desplaza mi app para abajo y me gustaría que solapase la ActionBar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para que se muestre por encima de la `ActionBar`, en la definición del tema actual `style.xml` añadir lo siguiente

```
<item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
```

Documentación [windowActionModeOverlay](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#windowActionModeOverlay)